# Is it possible to use robot_localization for multiple robots?

Tags: localization, gazebo, ekf, odometry, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm working on a small, multi-robot simulation using Husky robots. I've been using the base [husky_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_simulator) with some modifications to allow for multiple robots. The way I've accomplished this is through the use of namespaces. I call each "spawn_husky.launch" file in a separate namespace, which sets up all the plugins and publishes unique topics for each robot.

Everything seems to be working fine except for the the topics husky1/odometry/filtered and husky2/odometry/filtered. So I dug through the launch files and found that this topic is published in the control.launch file which uses a "robot_localization" node of the "ekf_localization_node" type.

The tf frame tree of a single robot simulation (without namespaces) looks like this:
[image: image description]

But when launched from within the namespace, with multiple robots, looks like this:

[image: image description]

I know it's hard to see, but the "odom" frame no longer exists, so this seems the localization is not working properly. My initial guess is that the robot_localization limits the parameters to "map" or "odom" but since I'm using a namespace and tf_prefix, it becomes "husky1/odom" and this is not allowed. But does anyone have any ideas as to how I might be able to correct this or why it might be happening?

Edit 1:
Some additional information, as requested by Tom.

Here are the frame_ids during a single robot simulation with no namespace or tf_prefix

```
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: base_footprint published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000202703 Max Delay: 0
Frame: base_laser published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: base_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -6.75676e-05 Max Delay: 0
Frame: front_bumper_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: front_left_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: front_right_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: imu_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: inertial_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: laser_mount_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: rear_bumper_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: rear_left_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: rear_right_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: topPlate published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: top_chassis_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: top_plate_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0
Frame: user_rail_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.000135135 Max Delay: 0

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 150.338 Hz, Average Delay: -6.94586e-05 Max Delay: 0
```

And here are all the frame_ids shown by tf_monitor when running the multi robot simulation:

```
RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: husky1/base_footprint published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/base_laser published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/front_bumper_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/front_left_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0185882 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/front_right_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0185882 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/imu_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/inertial_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/laser_mount_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/rear_bumper_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/rear_left_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0185882 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/rear_right_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0185882 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/topPlate published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/top_chassis_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/top_plate_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky1/user_rail_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0182353 Max Delay: 0.04
Frame: husky2/base_footprint published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/base_laser published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/front_bumper_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/front_left_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/front_right_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/imu_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/inertial_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/laser_mount_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/rear_bumper_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/rear_left_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/rear_right_wheel_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/topPlate published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/top_chassis_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/top_plate_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03
Frame: husky2/user_rail_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.0188824 Max Delay: 0.03

All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 200.59 Hz, Average Delay: 0.0186471 Max Delay: 0.04
```

And this is what my localization.yaml file looks like (it is left the same for both):

```
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: odom

two_d_mode: true

frequency: 50

odom0: husky_velocity_controller/odom
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, true,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false
odom0_queue_size: 10

imu0: imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false]
imu0_differential: true
imu0_queue_size: 10
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
print_diagnostics: true
```

I notice there are no "base_link" frames for the multi-robot version, but I'm not sure what this could mean.

Edit 2:

Here is the output from rqt_map on the working single robot:
[image: image description]

And now the output from the multi robot:
[image: image description]

So it looks like there are for input topics coming into the localization node for husky1. Here are examples of all:

/tf

```
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1597
        nsecs: 300000000
      frame_id: husky1/base_link
    child_frame_id: husky1/front_left_wheel_link
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 0.256
        y: 0.2854
        z: 0.03282
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.144187547375
        z: 0.0
        w: 0.989550378294
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1597
        nsecs: 300000000
      frame_id: husky1/base_link
    child_frame_id: husky1/front_right_wheel_link
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 0.256
        y: -0.2854
        z: 0.03282
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.157750826895
        z: 0.0
        w: 0.98747894996
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1597
        nsecs: 300000000
      frame_id: husky1/base_link
    child_frame_id: husky1/rear_left_wheel_link
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: -0.256
        y: 0.2854
        z: 0.03282
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: -0.158428913083
        z: 0.0
        w: 0.987370386177
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1597
        nsecs: 300000000
      frame_id: husky1/base_link
    child_frame_id: husky1/rear_right_wheel_link
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: -0.256
        y: -0.2854
        z: 0.03282
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: -0.192699433619
        z: 0.0
        w: 0.981257829667
```

/husky1/imu/data

```
header: 
  seq: 23902
  stamp: 
    secs: 1776
    nsecs: 540000000
  frame_id: base_link
orientation: 
  x: 0.000136499101278
  y: 1.42176279272e-05
  z: 0.00338303918051
  w: 0.999994268089
orientation_covariance: [2.6030820491461885e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.6030820491461885e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.00250481986211
  y: 0.000314847644066
  z: -0.00384896932272
angular_velocity_covariance: [2.5e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5e-05]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.00435986520834
  y: 0.00647963661132
  z: 9.79696593816
linear_acceleration_covariance: [2.5e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5e-05]
---
```

/husky1/husky_controller_velocity/odom

```
header: 
  seq: 29601
  stamp: 
    secs: 1890
    nsecs: 960000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.00760542738025
      y: -3.62838407179e-05
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.000862957133054
      w: 0.999999627652
  covariance: [0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 3.82179164307e-05
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -1.04046111105e-07
  covariance: [0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03]
---
```

And /tf_static

Which doesn't seem to be publishing anything.

Thanks all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226274/is-it-possible-to-use-robot_localization-for-multiple-robots?/) by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-02-11**:
Can you post sample messages for each input? I want to see the `frame_id`s. Also, even though I know what's in it, can you post the .yaml settings for `ekf_localization_node`? You can leave out the covariance matrices.

**Comment by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) on 2016-02-11**:
I just updated the post to include the frames and .yaml file. Let me know if anything else might be useful. Thanks!

**Comment by [Devin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25894/devin/) on 2016-02-11**:
[image: image description]
I think ekf/localization can subscribe topic odom and imu. But I cannot get /odometry/filtered neither.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-02-11**:
Can you post a sample input message for each input topic?

**Comment by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) on 2016-02-11**:
What do you mean by input topics? Are you referring to the topics used by the ekf_localization_node such as husky1/imu/data or husky2/husky_velocity_controller/odom?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-02-11**:
Yes. I need to see sample messages so I can verify frame_ids in the messages themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming that the `tf_prefix` tag is active for each robot. `r_l` will append the `tf_prefix` to the `frame_id`s specified in its launch file, even if the parameter is specified outside its configuration (we use `searchParam`). For example, for `husky1`, it's going to be trying to transform velocities to *husky1/base_link* and pose data to *husky1/odom*. However, all the incoming messages lack any `tf_prefix` (look at your IMU message: the `frame_id` is just *base_link*), so r_l doesn't know how to transform from *base_link* to *husky1/base_link*. I don't know if Gazebo supports prefixing those `frame_id`s, so one thing you might try is setting the `tf_prefix` parameter *inside* your r_l configuration to the empty string.

**EDIT 1 in response to comment**

I get the three separate `tf` trees; what is publishing the fourth `odom`->`base_link` transform?

`rviz` is going to yell at you here, as it doesn't know how to transform from each world (`huskyN/odom`) frame to the other, so you won't be able to display more than one robot at a time. One way to get around this is to define a frame that is a parent to all *N* of the Husky frames, and then set that to the fixed frame in `rviz`. To do this, you can just add three static transforms (using `static_transform_publisher` in the `tf` or `tf2` library), each with the same parent frame, and with the `huskyN/odom` frame as the child(ren).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) on 2016-02-16**:
Thank you! This worked, at least partially. Both husky#/odometry/filtered messages are now being published and have the correct data. However, there are now 3 tf trees: one for each robot and a third for odom->base_link. So rviz is throwing errors because it can't resolve between the three.

**Comment by [nbeyers](https://answers.ros.org/users/21511/nbeyers/) on 2016-03-01**:
In response to your edit: The **odom->base_link** transform was being published by robot_localization (since I was setting the **tf_prefix** to an empty string). I've since solved the issue by setting the **frame_id** parameter for both the IMU and the velocity controller for each robot.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-03-03**:
Great! So is your issue solved?

**Comment by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) on 2016-03-06**:
nbeyers - Could you explain how you set the "frame_id" parameter for the velocity controller in gazebo?  I have not been able to determine how/where the frame is set for the /husky_velocity_controller/odom topic.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-06**:
@Tom Moore But how would be define the transform between the parent frame and the N child frames (huskyN/odom) ? I mean, what would the value of the transforms?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2021-03-25**:
Do you mean how can you have all your robots in a common frame? You need a second EKF instance for each robot, and that EKF should generate a transform from the common parent frame (typically `map`) to the `huskyN/odom` frame for each robot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem and posted a solution here on/around Feb 16, 2016. A few days later, I was forced to remove the solution by my research advisor. I am no longer working on the project that motivated my solution, so I'm reposting it now in case it helps someone still having issues.

Source code for the amcl, robot_localization, and diff_drive_controller ROS **Indigo** packages were modified to introduce namespacing. The "map" frame serves as the global frame that allows multiple instances of localization. Please see [this github repo](https://github.com/proboscisjoe/roslab/tree/master/src). Package dependencies are included in a shell script in the root of the repo. Also, there is an example ROS node, leader_follower, that operated on two huskies: the first is controlled using keyboard teleop, and the second one follows the first one around.

The only outstanding issue that I didn't get around to working on is that models in rviz launch in the center of the frame no mater where the husky vehicle is launched in Gazebo. This is very annoying and it would be great if someone could solve that problem.

I wish this could have been in everyone's hands 14 months ago, but such is life.

---

Originally posted by [proboscisjoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26003/proboscisjoe/) with karma: 41 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4